# not showing pageMessages when search box is empty and direct click on the search button

Tags: apex, visualforce, pagemessages

**class code**

```
public class democlass {
 public string searchboxstring{get; set;}
 public list<contact> result {get; set;}
 public Integer counter{get;set;}

 public democlass(){
  //result = new list<Contact>();
 }
 public void searchbox(){
  result=new List<Contact>();
  if(searchBoxstring.trim() != null || searchBoxstring.trim() != ''){
      result=[select Name, account.name from Contact where account.Name =:searchboxstring];
      counter = result.size();
  }
  else{
      ApexPages.Message myMsg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,'please enter Account Name');
      ApexPages.addMessage(myMsg);
  }
 }
}
```

**this is page code**

```
<apex:page controller="democlass">  
<apex:form >
<apex:pageBlock >
<apex:pageMessages/>
 <apex:pageBlockSection columns="2">
 <apex:inputText value="{!searchBoxstring}" label="Search"/>
   <apex:commandButton value="Search" action="{!searchbox}" >
    <apex:commandButton value="Add" onclick="window.open=('/003','_blank');"/>
  </apex:commandButton>

    <apex:pageblockTable value="{!result}" var="wl">
     <apex:column title="Name">
          <apex:outputLink value="/{!wl.id}" target="_blank">{!wl.name}</apex:outputLink>
     </apex:column>
      <apex:column value="{!wl.account.name}"/>
      <apex:column value="{!wl.id}"/>
    </apex:pageblockTable>
    <br/><br/>
    <apex:outputText>Total Record : {!counter} </apex:outputText>   
  </apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update your if condition

```
if(searchBoxstring.trim() != null && searchBoxstring.trim() != ''){
      result=[select Name, account.name from Contact where account.Name =:searchboxstring];
      counter = result.size();
  }
  else{
      ApexPages.Message myMsg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,'please enter Account Name');
      ApexPages.addMessage(myMsg);
  }
```

because if its `null` then it will not equal to `empty string` and your condition will be satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

I feel couple of corrections in apex class can make it work

```
public class democlass {
 public string searchboxstring{get; set;}
 public list<contact> result {get; set;}
 public Integer counter{get;set;}

 public democlass(){
  //result = new list<Contact>();
 }
 public Pagereference searchbox(){
  result=new List<Contact>();
  if(searchBoxstring != null && searchBoxstring.trim() != ''){
      result=[select Name, account.name from Contact where account.Name =:searchboxstring];
      counter = result.size();
  }
  else{
      ApexPages.Message myMsg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,'please enter Account Name');
      ApexPages.addMessage(myMsg);
  }
 return null;
}
}
```